# How to solve a system of ODE with time dependent parameters in R?

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations, equation-solving, desolve

I am trying to solve this system of ODEs through deSolve, dX/dt = -X*a + (Y-X)*b + c and dY/dt = -Y*a + (X-Y)*b for time [0,200], a=0.30, b=0.2 but c is 1 for time [50,70] and 0 otherwise. The code I have been using is,

```
time <- seq(0, 200, by=1)
parameters <- c(a=0.33, b=0.2, c=1)
state <- c(X = 0, Y = 0)

    two_comp <- function(time, state, parameters){
      with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
        dX = -X*a + (Y-X)*b + c
        dY = -Y*a + (X-Y)*b
        return(list(c(dX, dY)))
      })
    }

out <- ode(y = state, times = time, func = two_comp, parms = parameters)
out.df = as.data.frame(out)
```

I have left out the time varying part of the c parameter since I can't figure out a way to include it and run it smoothly. I tried including it in the function definitions, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to use `approxfun`, i.e. create a time dependent signal, that we also call *forcing variable*:

```r
library("deSolve")
time <- seq(0, 200, by=1)
parameters <- c(a=0.33, b=0.2, c=1)
state <- c(X = 0, Y = 0)

two_comp <- function(time, state, parameters, signal){
  cc <- signal(time)
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dX <- -X * a + (Y - X) * b + cc
    dY <- -Y * a + (X - Y) * b
    return(list(c(dX, dY), c = cc))
  })
}

signal <- approxfun(x = c(0, 50, 70, 200), 
                    y = c(0, 1,  0,  0), 
                    method = "constant", rule = 2)

out <- ode(y = state, times = time, func = two_comp, 
           parms = parameters, signal = signal)
plot(out)
```

Note also the deSolve specific `plot` function and that the time dependent variable `cc` is used as an additional output variable.

[image: forcing]

More about this can be found:

- in the `?forcings` help page and
- in a [short tutorial](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html) on Github.

Answer (score 2):

The interval limits where `c` is equal to 1 can be passed as `parameters`. Then, inside the differential function, use them to create a logical value

```
time >= lower & time <= upper
```

Since `FALSE/TRUE` are coded as the integers `0/1`, every time this condition is false, `c` is multiplied by zero and the trick is done.

```
library(deSolve)

two_comp <- function(time, state, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dX = -X*a + (Y-X)*b + c*(time >= lower & time <= upper)
    dY = -Y*a + (X-Y)*b
    return(list(c(dX, dY)))
  })
}

time <- seq(0, 200, by=1)
parameters <- c(a=0.33, b=0.2, c=1, lower = 50, upper = 70)
state <- c(X = 0, Y = 0)

out <- ode(
  y = state, 
  times = time, 
  func = two_comp, 
  parms = parameters
)

out.df <- as.data.frame(out)
head(out.df)

matplot(out.df$time, out.df[-1], type = "l", lty = "solid", ylim = c(0, 3))
legend("topright", legend = names(out.df)[-1], col = 1:2, lty = "solid")
```

[image]